# Creating MVC application using Razor Engine and EF CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, ef-code-first

I am practicing Entity Framework. I am practicing Asp.net MVC framework using Razor Engine and EF Code First. In practicing it, I found to have few problems. The problem is the Entity Framework doesnt creates a database in my SQL.
I am using VisualStudio 2011 Beta Version with MSSQL 2008. I dont know what the problem is. 
Help required. Below is my Code :

```
    Person.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MvcDemo.Data
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public int LastName { get; set; }

        public int? Age { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PrefixID")]
        public Prefix Prefix { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public int PrefixID { get; set; }

    }
}

    Prefix.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MvcDemo.Data
{
    public class Prefix
    {
        public int PrefixID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string PrefixName { get; set; }
    }
}

MvcContext.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MvcDemo.Data;


namespace MvcDemo.DataAccess
{
    public class MvcContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcContext()
            : base("name = MvcDemoApp")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MvcDemo.Data.Prefix> Prefix { get; set; }

    }
}

ConnectionString:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MvcDemoApp" 
         connectionString="Server=.;Initial Catalog=MvcDemoApp;Integrated Security=true" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all of your code it is not surprising that a database is not created. There is no code that executes commands against the database. As soon as you start iterating over e.g. `MvcContext.People` or do some insert you will notice that the database gets created.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty step-by-step examples online. I would pick one of them and do a walk through; you can try this one for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467.aspx. It should cover most of the basics to get you started.

If you prefer video over text, search [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/HanselminutesOn9/Hanselminutes-on-9-Digging-into-Entity-Framework-4-Code-First-Magic-Unicorn-Edition), or [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/)

Answer (score 0):

You should operate package manager console to do it.

Ope package manager console window and run "update-database" command, there still a bug in this command so you need to specify "startupprojectname" param to execute it and connection string in you DbContext file.